# Parameter fine tuning for training Alexnet with smaller image size

Tags: caffe, conv-neural-network

Alexnet is intended to use 227x227x3 image size.
If I like to train the image size smaller like 32x80x3, what are the parameters to be fine tuned.

I initially trained with 64x80x3 image sizes with all parameters same as provided except the stride in the first Conv1 layer, it was changed to 2.
I achieved the testing accuracy very high and as high as 0.999. Then in real use also, I get reasonable high in accuracy in detection.

Then I prefer to use the smaller image size 32x80x3. I used the same parameters as trained in 64x80x3 image size, but accuracy is as low as 0.9671.
I tried to fine tune parameters like Conv1 layer's filer size to 5. Gaussian weight filter's std size to 10 times and 100 times smaller. But none of them can help achieve the accuracy achieved in training 64x80x3 images.

For smaller image sizes to train, what are the parameters to be fine tuned to achieve the higher accuracy?
I used 24000 dataset. 20000 is for training and 4000 is for testing.

For both 32x80x3 and  64x80x3, I used same images, just that image size is edited to be 32x80 and 64x80.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can train to resize the `32x80x3 images to 64x80x3` and then use the similar parameter settings.
Also, maybe you could find some thing useful here https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/examples/cifar10.
There are some solver and train_val files for fine tuning over `CIFAR-10`, which is a dataset consists of small images too.